# Why are there so many duplicate pods in my kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubectl

Here is an example:

This is the output of `kubectl get pods`:

```
loki-grafana-676b54679f-229sm                   0/2     Completed                0              27m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-2wxfr                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              9h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-4qr6q                   0/2     Completed                0              88m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-4zjbm                   0/2     Completed                0              3h10m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-5xpsc                   0/2     Completed                0              5h13m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-66n65                   0/2     ContainerCreating        0              10m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-7gzm7                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              14h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-7mb86                   0/2     Completed                0              17h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-7s7zw                   0/2     Completed                0              12h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-7vj66                   0/2     Error                    0              16h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-9jcj9                   0/2     Error                    0              5h28m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-b6n7z                   0/2     Completed                0              19h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-clljv                   0/2     Error                    0              6h27m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-fslvm                   0/2     Completed                0              3d6h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-h86qr                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   1              4h28m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-hffjx                   0/2     Completed                0              20h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-j2tl5                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              16h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-l2t9s                   0/2     Completed                0              9h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-l774q                   0/2     Completed                0              10h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-lf5fb                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              15h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-lqjmr                   0/2     Completed                0              6h12m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-lzrwm                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              3h27m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-mkrft                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              12h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-ntfk2                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              6d20h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-p95df                   0/2     Completed                0              8h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-r67gd                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   2              8h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-rc7qw                   0/2     Completed                0              15h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-rv2lq                   0/2     Error                    0              17h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-s9f7l                   0/2     Completed                0              7h27m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-sk5dv                   0/2     Completed                0              11h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-smlrc                   0/2     Error                    0              13h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-t2wf6                   0/2     ContainerStatusUnknown   1              18h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-vkz4g                   0/2     Completed                0              13h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-w4czd                   0/2     Completed                0              151m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-whbbq                   0/2     Completed                0              19h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-wqrkt                   0/2     Completed                4 (21h ago)    3d4h
loki-grafana-676b54679f-wsnls                   0/2     Completed                0              4h12m
loki-grafana-676b54679f-xkqmg                   0/2     Completed                0              136m
```

Is is unsual or should I do something about this?

I was diagnosing why grafana wasn't working and was about to get the pod name to check the logs

Comment: Many of them are completed jobs... kubernetes does not delete them automatically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are completed jobs. If you don't want to see so many of them, then you will have to configure job history limits; specifically `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` in the grafana `Job` spec.

More info here: [Job History Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits).